# Cannot see php file request in network tab

Tags: php

I developed my own mvc framework but I've a problem with the php file request.
My framework shunk all request by .htaccess that have this content:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /MVC/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

so in my router I split the url like this:

```
$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
$url = rtrim($url, '/');
$url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$this->_url = explode('/', $url);

if (file_exists($this->_url)) 
{
     require $this->_url;
     new $this->_url[0]();
     return true; //controller found
}
```

and load the controller in this way, the problem's that in the network tab of chrome or
any other browser I cannot see any request of the file but it's loaded correctly.

This is a problem for me 'cause I cannot check if there is an error in the file, or if I want
dump a variable I cannot see the content directly in the console of the browser.

Any chance to fix this?

**EXAMPLE:**

If I put this request url in the browser: http://localhost/MVC/user

that will load the `user.php` file controller, I get this in the network console:

[image]

Now the controller is loaded 'cause I can see the webpage (the controller user load the view in the index function), but I cannot see it in the network tab.

Comment: If it's just for debug purposes you can probably just change `[QSA,L]` to `[R=301,QSA,L]` to get a proper redirect rather than a rewrite.

Comment: @apokryfos unfortunately not working, thanks anyway for the hint. I update my question with more details and an image example

Comment: @apokryfos this is an incredible question, I don't know why don't get serious response.

Comment: Ok let me put it this way. "Rewrite" is a server side thing. The client side doesn't see the rewrite happening and will think that the actual file that is being accessed is the one in the address bar. I suggested a redirect because that way you'd get the 301 response status in the network tab with the new URL instead of the 200 status. However as @kcp suggested , you need to be seeing *all* activity (and also preserving the log) to see all this going on.

Comment: Also saying that the people who did respond to this did not offer "a serious response" is not helping.

Answer (score 4):

You have selected JS tab, switch it to All.

[image: Solution:]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fix the problem I see more content but no php file

Comment: You load only index.php file via browser, because user.php file is loaded via PHP script.

Comment: I uploaded another image so you can see that there is no php file. Anyway, no change for do this code behind such as other framework?

Comment: Your browser get only response from server, not file by file (PHP files are included to one by script).

Comment: any solution for this? What I can do?

Answer (score 0):

An apache rewrite takes a URL and changes it based on a set of rules and then serves the rewritten resource rather than the file originally accessed. However, this happens on the server side and is not visible to the client, therefore this information is not accessible to the client side.

The one way for the client side to see this is if the server redirects rather than rewrites and this in fact will be shown as a visible change of the address bar. However redirecting will probably break lots of things which rely on the accessed URL to serve content. So overall, no you can't use your browser to figure out the rewrites your server did, this is also a big security concern if you were able to do this.

I suggest you set up the apache rewrite log instead by following the instructions at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html . This logging is done by apache itself, is on the server side, and is the recommended way to debug rewrite rules.